# Android Canvas.drawCircle() half the size it should be

Tags: android, canvas

I have a custom view with the following drawing code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, mPaint);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, mPaint);
}
```

This should draw a square, and then a circle that is twice the size of the square, centred on one of its corners. Instead the circle is the same size as the square.

In other words. It should look like the image on the left, but it actually looks like the image on the right. What gives?

[image: Correct rendering on left; actual rendering on right]

Comment: Are you sure about your code? I just tried the code above and it produces the result on the left, as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after testing, this appears to be a bug in the GUI layout editor. I was assuming this would match the results on the device since they actually run the code... and it's a very weird bug that it only affects circles!

Also it is a more complicated bug than just doubling the values. Sometimes drawCircle() draws an ellipse!

Anyway it works as expected on the device.

Comment: Update to this: I submitted this as a bug ages ago (just after I submitted the question) and they fixed it.